# How to use a variable within a method elsewhere in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

I know this is a stupid question, but I'm asking as a newbie to flutter.

I created a getData() method to call Firebase's User data and display it on the app. And to call it, result.data() is saved as a variable name of resultData.

But as you know I can't use Text('user name: $resultData'). How do I solve this? It's a difficult problem for me, since I don't have any programming basics. thank you.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _authentication = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? loggedUser;
  final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  void getData() async {
    var result = await firestore.collection('user').doc('vUj4U27JoAU6zgFDk6sSZiwadQ13').get();
    final resultData = result.data();
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    getData();
  }

  void getCurrentUser(){
    try {
      final user = _authentication.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedUser = user;
        print(loggedUser!.email);
      }
    } catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Home Screen'),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Get.to(()=>LoginScreen());
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.to(() => LoginScreen());
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.login),
            ),
            Text('UserInfo'),
            Text('user name:  ')

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is called [state](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).
It is a complex topic and you will have to start studying it to correctly develop any web based app.

Anyway, as for your situation, you should have `resultData` be one of the attributes of the `_HomeScreenState` class.

Then change `resultData` in a setState method, like this:

```
setState(() {
  resultData = result.data();
});
```

Then, in the `Text` widget, you can actually do something like:

```
Text("My data: " + resultData.ToString())
```

Instead of `ToString` of course, use anything you need to actually access the data.

Comment: Appreciate your kind reply. I think I should study the state a little more in-depth. As you said, I declared a variable  _HomeScreenState class and it use again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By writing

```
  void getData() async {
    var result = await firestore.collection('user').doc('vUj4U27JoAU6zgFDk6sSZiwadQ13').get();
    final resultData = result.data();
  }
```

you make `resultData` only local to the function `getData()`. You should declare it outside. Also you need to put it in a `setState` to make it rebuild the screen after loading. I don't know what type it is, but if it's a String for example you could write

```
  String? resultData;

  void getData() async {
    var result = await firestore.collection('user').doc('vUj4U27JoAU6zgFDk6sSZiwadQ13').get();
    setState(() {
      resultData = result.data();
    });  
  }
```

Then you can use `Text('user name: $resultData')` for example

Comment: Appreciate your reply. It works fine :) Firestore data's type was map, so I used 'var resultData;' rather than String?. Thank you.